# Print Preview in ReportViewer display blank screen

Tags: vbscript, reportviewer, page-setup

Below is the code for the new page setting:

```
Dim newPageSettings As New PageSettings
newPageSettings.Margins = New Margins(20, 20, 20, 20)
newPageSettings.Landscape = True
Dim paperSize As PaperSize = New PaperSize()
paperSize.RawKind = PaperKind.A4
newPageSettings.PaperSize = paperSize
ReportViewer1.SetPageSettings(newPageSettings)
Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

After I debug the system and click Print Preview in ReportViewer, the screen display as below:[image]

I seriously don't know how this happen. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have already found a solution for above issue. Instead of using coding to setup setting for print preview, I change the Report Setting in rdlc. Please see below picture for more info:
[image: Click the Report Properties]

[image: Change to the right setting]